# Standard Template Library lists - doubly linked or circularly linked?

Tags: c++, list, stl, iterator

I've just noticed something about the `std::list` class in C++ I find curious. Briefly, it concerns the manner in which the list's iterators work. Consider the following code:

```
std::list<int> alist;
alist.push_back(0);
alist.push_back(1);
alist.push_back(2);
```

Obviously enough, this creates a list with three integer elements in it. I can define an iterator to the start of the list and use it to, say, print out the value contained in the first element as follows:

```
std::list<int>::iterator iter = alist.begin();
std::cout << *iter << std::endl;  // Prints "0" to stdout
```

What I find mildly odd is that if I now *decrement* the iterator, it "loops around" and ends up pointing at the last element in the list:

```
--iter;
std::cout << *iter << std::endl;  // Prints "2" to stdout
```

Is this reasonable behaviour for something that's supposedly implemented as a doubly linked list? I'd quite expect to similar behaviour from the iterator if the list was a *circularly* linked list, but I find this quite odd.

Are there any practical uses for this iterator behaviour that you've used in the past? Are there any gotchas associated with this behaviour that I should keep an eye out for?

(By the way, this happens with gcc 4.7.0 (MinGW). I haven't tested it with any other version or compiler.)

Comment: It prints -1218668059 for me http://ideone.com/3kpQf

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Decrementing the iterator beyond `begin` invokes undefined behaviour.  The behaviour you're seeing is quite likely to be coincidence (indeed, see what happens with a different compiler [here](http://ideone.com/hc7pP)).

If you want to confirm this, you can simply take a look at the implementation of GCC's `list`; you can usually find the source at `/usr/include/c++/4.x.y/bits/stl_list.h`.

Comment: Thanks for that. Reading the source has helped clear things up nicely. (Thanks for the link to ideone too - not seen that before!)

Comment: Actually I have seen in a few implementations the use of a hidden node that closes the circle. The use of that *guard* allows for easier implementation of the rest of the operations, insert/erase do not need to special-case the beginning/end of the list, they can just operate on `node->last` and `node->next` (however they are called in the implementation) knowing that it refers to a valid *object*.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at stl_list.h, I noticed this comment:

```
   *
   *  Second, a %list conceptually represented as
   *  @code
   *    A <---> B <---> C <---> D
   *  @endcode
   *  is actually circular; a link exists between A and D.  The %list
   *  class holds (as its only data member) a private list::iterator
   *  pointing to @e D, not to @e A!  To get to the head of the %list,
   *  we start at the tail and move forward by one.  When this member
```

This was found in 4.2.1 gcc. This doesn't change the answer provided by @Oli as it happens to be the one it was implemented in gcc 4.2.1. I would count on that functionality

Comment: The comment is slightly misleading with respect to the implementation.  The implementation of the list in that version of the STL defines a node base type that holds just the pointers, and node implementations that extends the node base and includes the actual data. The list holds a node base instance which is what closes the loop (and incidentally the `end()` iterator). The detail that makes the difference is that the *link* that closes the list cannot be a node holding data, or else it would be impossible to perform the most simple loop.

Answer (score 0):

i think the "2" you got is the constant 2(in `alist.push_back(2);`).
i think you program is very short and simple, am i right?